# What if git repository gets corrupted?

Tags: backup, git

Git keeps track of every change you've made to your project. So it feels much safer to work on something knowing that, even if system crashes and current files you were working in get corrupted, there will still be the latest version you've commited in the `.git` folder. But what if some files in that folder get corrupted. Does git keep an extra backup of them as well?

I'm also curious how git handles writing to files. Does it create backups while writing for in case of a crash it can recover? Or does it just write directly to the files? I know git is open source, but the source code is too overwhelming for a beginner like me to understand...

Comment: well, this is why Git is often used with an upstream server (origin). if your local .git folder gets corrupted, that corruption won't be propagated upstream to the server, so you should always be able to get a clean copy, minus your most recent changes.  as for your question, most of the files in .git are not changed when you add a new commit. it will have a completely different folder structure, and will not change existing commit files. commits are monolithic and store a full copy of the codebase at that time.

Comment: You seem to confuse a version control system and backups. Neither can replace the other.

Comment: Other than code, Git uses centralized files for logging and pointers, like HEADS, refs, and logs. these files are modified to point to or include info on the latest commit, but these files should be fixable, either by using git commands (prefered), or by modifying the files to point where you want. These files are Text, and often indicate another file like a commit ID or a Head. overall, git is somewhat resistant to write-time corruption, though other kinds of damage like filesystem or disk corruption however could have a bigger impact than just losing the latest commit or whatever.

Comment: @FrankThomas what if the upstream server's .git folder gets corrupted?

Comment: Git doesn't just upload files. it uses command semantics to push changes, so while a content (a code) file included in the repo could become corrupted from one commit to the next, you always have the prior version of the file.  Meta files in .git are not transferred from local to origin, they are used by the code to signal changes to the server, because each system will have an entirely different copy of the .git folder, so the metadata is maintained separately on the server and the client. that way you can't break git. the worst you can do is corrupt a code file or two, which can be recovered

Comment: I'd like to add that the "upstream server" can simply be another directory on your same server, perhaps in /opt/backup, or any path location you wish. You can tell git that your "remote" is called "backup" and is located in "/opt/backup/mysrc.git", and then manually back up your git repo with commands like "git push backup master". I was inspired by reading https://thehorrors.org.uk/snippets/git-local-filesystem-remotes/

Comment: Regarding your second question: how it handles writing _which_ files?

Answer (score 1):

This seems like common misconception about git.
Git is not backup solution.
You can use git to backup things and it (usually) work but there's no dedicated, fool-proof logic to prevent data loss on file corruption. You can (and arguably should) push your local files to some remote (which can be private) which would increase resilience to corruption - but that's it.
If you like versioning using Git and would like to read more on topic of backing it up you can check out [Git Backup Guide](https://xopero.com/resources/git-backup-guide/)